# Shared Key Lite authentication scheme validity with azure storage service

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-storage

I read in MS msdn site [[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx)] about the Shared Key Lite authentication scheme for the azure storage service access . It was mentioned that Shared Key Lite signature is valid for 15 mins, this avoids the replay attacks. But my question is, why such a long duration for validity? During 15 mins time span replay attacks can happen right?

Answer (score 4):

> But my question is, why such a long duration for validity?

Think of this 15 minutes as a buffer to take care of any clock skewness. It may be entirely possible that the clock on the machine from where you're creating the authorization header is not in sync with clocks in Windows Azure and you obviously don't want exact time match between the 2 systems for the authorization to succeed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like it is the right ans. Still replay attacks can happen right? Anybody can catch a request and resend it with his request to get access to storage?

Comment: That's why it is recommended that you communicate over https to avoid "man-in-the-middle" issues if you're communicating with storage from outside of Windows Azure.